# SQL Server 2008 GUID column is all 0's

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, guid

I'm hoping this is a simple goof I did on my end ...

I have a table in my database set up like so:

```
column name: widget_guid
data type: uniqueidentifier
allow nulls: false
default value: newid()
identity: false
row guid: true
```

When records are created (via LINQ to SQL) that the values in this field are formatted as a GUID but contain all 0's

My assumption was that when a new record was created, that a guid would be autogenerated for that column, much like an auto-incrementing row id.  Is this not true?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: When you create a record in your application code, are you passing in a Guid or leaving it blank and letting the DB auto-populate?

Also, you should try passing in a `Guid.NewGuid()` in your application code to trace it.

Comment: i'm wanting the database server to create it using newid().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check your properties on the GUID column - what you need to make sure is:

- `Auto Generated Values` is set to `True` (so you basically tell Linq-to-SQL that the database will generate the value)
- `Auto-Sync` should be set to `OnInsert` so that your C# object will be populated with the new value after you've called `context.SubmitChanges()`

With these two settings, you should get the expected behavior: no need to set the GUID on the client side, the database will generate a new value and insert it, and you'll get it back right after the call to `.SubmitChanges()`

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if the "Auto Generated Value" property were set to "True" if the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER column's RowGuid property was set to "Yes"...

Comment: And, unfortunately, it appears this setting would be lost the next time you generate your model data from the database!

Comment: @marc_s, I've been trying to find the above settings on SQL Server 2016 with no luck. How do you find these?

Comment: @Alex: that was a setting in Visual Studio, in the Linq-2-SQL datamodel (`.dbml` file) - not in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

In  your dbml file, set the field to nullable.
If it is set to not-nullable, LINQ does not go as far as checking that the field has a default; it simply believes the field non-nullable and will send Guid.Empty causing the 0's.